# Select all days of the current week

Tags: sql-server

Good Day! I am working on a chart where I need to display all the days of the current week to show the sales per Week. So far, I am able to display all the days of the current week, I'm just having a trouble in displaying the sales for each day of the week.Since there are no records in the database for the days of the week, it the TOTAL_SALES column should all return a Null value. Instead, it returns the total sales recorded in the database. Here is my Stored Procedure query so far.

```html
WITH DAYSOFTHEWEEK AS 
(
  SELECT 0 DAY
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DAY + 1 FROM DAYSOFTHEWEEK WHERE DAY < 6
)
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, DAY, DATEADD(DAY, 2-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, CONVERT (date, GETDATE())), CONVERT (date, GETDATE()))) AS DAY_OF_THE_WEEK,
  SUM([ORDER].NET_AMOUNT) AS TOTAL_SALES
    FROM DAYSOFTHEWEEK, [ORDER]
 GROUP BY DAYSOFTHEWEEK.DAY
```

I tried adding this condition statement,

```
WHERE DAYSOFTHEWEEK.DAY IN ([ORDER].ORDER_DATE)
```

But it returns this error

```
Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int
```

Can someone help me out on this?Is there a work around with the code that I already have? Thanks in advance!

Comment: So your `ORDER` table has `ORDER_DATE` and something like `NET_AMOUNT`? Perhaps you can post some sample data?

Comment: what day do you want the week to start on?

Comment: @LesH , i do have a table named ORDER that has the ORDER_DATE and NET_AMOUNT.

Comment: @AndrewDeighton it should start on Sunday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think you're after is a `SUM` of each day's sales for the current week with `NULL` if there are no sales. The secret is to left join your date list onto your data:

```
-- Setup some fake sales data
WITH TestData(N, Order_Date, Net_Amount) AS (
    SELECT 1 N, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) Order_Date, RAND() * 100 Net_Amount
    UNION ALL
    SELECT N+1 N, CAST(GETDATE()-N/5 AS DATE) Order_Date, RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 100 Net_Amount FROM TestData
    WHERE N < 20
    )
SELECT TestData.Order_Date, TestData.Net_Amount INTO #Order FROM TestData

--Set the first day of the week (if required)
SET DATEFIRST 7 --Sunday


;WITH Days(N,DayOfTheWeek)  AS (
    SELECT 1 N, DATEADD(DAY,  1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())) DayOfTheWeek
    UNION ALL
    SELECT N+1 N,DATEADD(DAY, 1, DayOfTheWeek) DayOfTheWeek FROM Days
    WHERE N < 7
)
SELECT d.DayOfTheWeek, SUM(Net_Amount) TotalAmount 
FROM Days d
LEFT JOIN #Order ON d.DayOfTheWeek = Order_Date
GROUP BY d.DayOfTheWeek

DayOfTheWeek TotalAmount
------------ ----------------------
2016-08-07   219.036784917497
2016-08-08   273.319570812461
2016-08-09   271.148114731087
2016-08-10   194.780039228967
2016-08-11   NULL
2016-08-12   NULL
2016-08-13   NULL
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Your query displayed the week today starting from 2016-08-07 (Sunday) just as what I wanted to display.

Answer (score 0):

A little over complicated for me:
To get name of the week use, for example

`SELECT DATENAME(dw,getdate())`

But you really need something like this:

```
SELECT ProductName,Sum(Sales) From NameOfTable  GROUP BY
 DATENAME(ww,salesDate)
```

Comment: The things is, I need to select all the days of the current week. Your query only lists the current day of the week.

Comment: See next query... DATENAME(ww,getDate()) will give you the number of the week for the input date. So you will be able to group your records by week.

Comment: Oh now I get you: 

SELECT CAST(salesDate as DATE) as salesDay,ProductName,Sum(Sales) From NameOfTable 
GROUP BY CAST(salesDate as DATE)

Answer (score 0):

Here is every day this week, starting at your datefirst date, which can be temporarily varied for the query with SET DATEFIRST if you need to have some other week start date

I think you have some sales table there that you haven't shown us, you need to join to that on date, then group by

```
    WITH DAYSOFTHEWEEK AS 
(
  SELECT cast(dateadd(
                        day,
                         -datepart(weekday,getdate()) + 1  , 
                        GETDATE()
                        )
            as date)  [DAY], 0 as cnt
  UNION ALL
  SELECT dateadd(day,1,[DAY]), cnt + 1  FROM DAYSOFTHEWEEK WHERE cnt < 6
)
select DAYSOFTHEWEEK.[day], SUM([ORDER].NET_AMOUNT) AS TOTAL_SALES from  daysoftheweek
                                              JOIN
                                              SalesTable on
                                   CAST(SalesTable.SalesDate date) = DAYSOFTHEWEEK.[day]
                           GROUP BY DAYSOFTHEWEEK.[day]
```